# Block file not loading in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, frontend, page

I created a custom module.I want to get the updated details to a front-end page from back-end.

My **routes.xml** file is - (Ayakil\Bannermanager\etc\frontend)

```
...
<router id="standard">
    <route id="homebanner" frontName="homebanner">
        <module name="Ayakil_Bannermanager" />
    </route>
</router>
...
```

Layout file is **homebanner_index_index.xml** - (Ayakil\Bannermanager\view\frontend\layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">e
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Ayakil\Bannermanager\Block\Index\Index" name="homebanner"  template="Ayakil_Bannermanager::bannermanager.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Template file is **bannermanager.phtml** - (Ayakil\Bannermanager\view\frontend\templates)

```
<h1><?php echo $this->getHomepageBanners(); ?></h1>
```

Block file **Index.php** - (Ayakil\Bannermanager\Block\Index)

```
<?php

namespace Ayakil\Bannermanager\Block\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

protected $_bannersFactory;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
\Ayakil\Rewardpoints\Model\BannersFactory $bannersFactory,
array $data = array()
) {
    $this->_bannersFactory = $bannersFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


protected function _prepareLayout()
{   
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function getHomepageBanners(){

    $Banners = $this->_bannersFactory->create();
    $collection = $Banners->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('banner_location',1);
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('banner_active',1);

    return $collection->setOrder('id','DESC');
}//End of function getHomepageBanners
}//End of class
```

Controller file **Index.php** - (**\Ayakil\Bannermanager\Controller\Index**)

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\Bannermanager\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory; 

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;



class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Here i if i type the url its comes to controller, but block file is not reaching.What is my issue in my layout file?

**UPDATE**

I am getting this error in system.log file

> [2017-10-31 06:09:36] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_49616ea6e172f105633873ece31b228de and handles default, homebanner_index_index: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

Comment: did you remove var/generation folder?

Comment: nope, i clear cashe, and run upgrade?

Comment: just remove var/generation folder and check

Comment: did i missed any flows during my code ?

Comment: did you check after remove generation folder

Comment: @Rakesh yes. still block is not reaching

Answer (score 1):

try to change your code from `bannermanager.phtml` file

```
<h1><?php echo $this->getHomepageBanners(); ?></h1>
```

to

```
<?php /** @var $block \Ayakil\Bannermanager\Block\Index\Index */ ?>

<h1><?php echo $block->getHomepageBanners(); ?></h1>
```

layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Ayakil\Bannermanager\Block\Index\Index" name="homebanner"  template="Ayakil_Bannermanager::bannermanager.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and run `clean` and `flush` commands. It's working for me.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I have a Demo  Page Content in bannermanager.phtml its also not viewing

Comment: @Mujahidh any errors?

Comment: no errors, in my case the page is not reaching the bannermanager.phtml.hope there was an issue in my layout xml wich unable to figure out by my self

Comment: @Mujahidh see layout file updated my answer. Please check your `exception.log` and `system.log` file you will get error details.

Comment: my layout file is same as your in the answer

Comment: @Mujahidh have you created `registration.php` and `module.xml` files?

Comment: yes my extension is working fine.i can add the data from admin pannel also

Comment: i am getting an error.i updated the question with error

Answer (score 0):

Here my issues is my layout xml file.

I changed this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

to this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

worked me fine.